# moving absolute; element at 1600 resolution with media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have one button that I must position absolute in accordance with what I'm doing. This is fine; except at `1600px resolution` - the button goes out of the screen; I want to utilize media queries to fix this, but my first two efforts are not working and moving the element at the specified viewport and I'm not sure.. why.

*Attempt # 1:*

```
@media screen and (min-width:1600px) { /* large resolution */ 
    #menu_tog { margin-left: 337px; }
}
```

*Attempt # 2:*

```
@media (max-width:1600px;) and (min-width:1300px;) { /* large resolution */ 
    #menu_tog { margin-left: 337px;}
}
```

*Original (expect position change at 1600)*

```
#menu_tog {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 138px;
    margin-top: 230px;
    max-height: 35px;
    max-width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: you realized that you gave the `#menu_tog` an absolute position right?

Comment: Are your media queries before or after your general CSS? If they are before, add !important to the rules you want to override.

Comment: Thanks this wasn't the issue; nor the absolute; but the margin-left over left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using `top` and `left` with absolutely-positioned elements, not margins. From there, a simple media query should do the job:

```css
#menu_tog {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    left: 138px;
    top: 230px;
    max-height: 35px;
    max-width: 50px;
    z-index: 999;
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    #menu_tog {
        left: 337px; /* adjust as necessary */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats it! I always forget the tiniest things!